Problems with t test in R
I´m trying to perform a t-test with the variables EM03, EM02, EM03. These variables are expressions of the Variable EM05.
For context, I did a survey, where I showed 3 types of experimental manipulations(EM01, EM02,EM03), which were coincidentally drawn with the help of a random generator (EM05).
I want to perform the T-test with the variables EM01/EM02/EM03 x eins_index each.
When I try to launch the T-test, it wont run.  It shows this error: #Error in t.test.default(mig_neutral_stim$einst_index, mig_neutral_stim$EM05,  : not enough 'x' observations
how can I modify the code to make it run?  I appreciate every tip !!!
thank you guys in advance !!!
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(report)
library(psych)

#Datensatz einlesen:
mig <- readxl::read_excel("data/data_ExperimentMigration2024_2024-07-04_20-34.xlsx")

#Items umpolen

#Zuwanderung wirkt sich negativ auf die Wirtschaft aus.
mig <- mutate(mig, new_ME03_09 = case_when(
  ME03_09== 1 ~ 5,
  ME03_09== 2 ~ 4,
  ME03_09== 3 ~ 3,
  ME03_09== 4 ~ 2,
  ME03_09== 5 ~ 1
))


#Flucht vor Armut ist weniger legitim als Flucht vor Krieg oder aus politischen Gründen.
mig <- mutate(mig, new_ME03_04 = case_when(
  ME03_04== 1 ~ 5,
  ME03_04== 2 ~ 4,
  ME03_04== 3 ~ 3,
  ME03_04== 4 ~ 2,
  ME03_04== 5 ~ 1
))


#Asylsuchende nehmen Deutschen die Arbeitsplätze weg.
mig <- mutate(mig, new_ME03_02 = case_when(
  ME03_02== 1 ~ 5,
  ME03_02== 2 ~ 4,
  ME03_02== 3 ~ 3,
  ME03_02== 4 ~ 2,
  ME03_02== 5 ~ 1
))


#Zuwanderung verschlimmert die Wohnungsknappheit.
mig <- mutate(mig, new_ME03_01 = case_when(
  ME03_01== 1 ~ 5,
  ME03_01== 2 ~ 4,
  ME03_01== 3 ~ 3,
  ME03_01== 4 ~ 2,
  ME03_01== 5 ~ 1
))


#Index Bilden
#Variablen in numerische Werte konvertieren
mig_selected <- mig |>
  select(new_ME03_01, new_ME03_02, ME03_03, new_ME03_04, ME03_05, ME03_07, new_ME03_09, ME03_10) |>
  mutate(across(everything(), as.numeric))
einst_index <- mig_selected |>
  rowMeans(na.rm = TRUE)
mig <- mig |>
  mutate(einst_index = einst_index)
mig |> #Mittelwert + SD vom Index
  summarise(
    mean_einst_index = mean(einst_index, na.rm = TRUE),
    sd_einst_index = sd(einst_index, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
#sicherstellen das mig ein dataframe ist 
mig <- as.data.frame(mig)

# Überprüfen der Struktur der Daten
str(mig)

# Sicherstellen, dass 'einst_index' numerisch ist
mig$einst_index <- as.numeric(mig$einst_index)

# Daten filtern nach neutralem Stimulus (EM03)
mig_neutral_stim <- mig |> 
  filter(EM05 == "EM03") |> 
  select(einst_index, EM05)  # Annahme, dass EM_05 die entsprechenden Werte enthält

# Sicherstellen, dass 'EM05' numerisch ist
mig_neutral_stim$EM05 <- as.numeric(mig_neutral_stim$EM05)

# Überprüfen auf fehlende Werte und Paare mit fehlenden Werten entfernen
mig_neutral_stim <- mig_neutral_stim |> 
  filter(!is.na(einst_index) & !is.na(EM05)

# t-Test durchführen
t.test(mig_neutral_stim$einst_index, mig_neutral_stim$EM05, paired = TRUE)
         
#Error in t.test.default(mig_neutral_stim$einst_index, mig_neutral_stim$EM05,  : not enough 'x' observations



Hi @Alina, welcome to SO and thank you for your question. It appears to me that your example contains a lot of code that is not relevant for your question and that the example is not reproducible as you don't supply the data set (and probably shouldn't due to data protection issues). Maybe it would help you to learn how to write a good R question with a reproducible example. All the best!

I believe that this kind of error appears when the two vectors in the paired t-test do not have the same length. For a paired t-test, each element of the first vector (mig_neutral_stim$einst_index in your case) should have a matching element in the second vector (mig_neutral_stim$EM05 in your case).
I supply a brief example that reproduces a similar error:
x <- c(1, 2, 3)
y <- c(1.5, 1.9, 3.5)
x_too_short <- c(1, 2)
t.test(x, y, paired = TRUE)
# No error message
t.test(x_too_short, y, paired = TRUE)
# Error in complete.cases(x, y) : not all arguments have the same length

To reproduce the precise error message and to help you more specifically, you would need to supply a runnable reproducible example.
